# Exception The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'type'

Tags: jsf

Exception occurs while trying to get object value.
It worked before when our application has only web-application in ear, but when we add ejb package with APP-INF/lib into application.xml exception appears: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'type'. In my investigation here: item value is String but not object returned by getItems method. Why this exception may occurs.

Thanks for any ideas.

Here is the code of jsp page.

```
<div id="report_items">
<c:forEach items="#{repcatTree.items}" var="item">
   <div style="padding-top:7px; padding-bottom:7px; padding-right:15px;">
      <span class="report_item_category_class">
         <h:commandLink rendered="#{item.type == 'category'}" action="#{item.onNodeClicked}" 
               styleClass="default_link">
            <h:graphicImage url="/views/tree/images/folder_big.gif" />
            <h:outputText value="#{item.attributes.FILE_NAME}" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-left:5px" />
         </h:commandLink>
         <h:commandLink rendered="#{item.type == 'report'}" styleClass="default_link" 
                    action="action_report_run" title="#{item.cells['report_name'].toolTip}">
            <h:graphicImage url="/icon?rdd_path=#{item.attributes.RDD_PATH}" />               
            <h:outputText value="#{item.cells['report_name'].display}"
                             style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-left:5px" />

            <f:param name="nodePath" value="#{item.attributes.RDD_PATH}" />
            <f:param name="nodePrettyPath" value="#{item.attributes.CAT_PATH}" />
          </h:commandLink>
      </span>
   </div>
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

Here is my class. I remove no needed part of code.

```
public class RepcatTreeModel extends TreeModel implements Serializable {

   public RepcatTreeModel() {
      super();
   }

   public Collection getItems() {
       items = new ArrayList();
       items.addAll(getActiveNode().getChildren());
       items.addAll(getTableModel().getRows());
       Object[] _items = items.toArray();
       Arrays.sort(_items, new Comparator() {
           public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
               int result = 0;
               if (o1 instanceof TreeNodeModel && o2 instanceof TreeNodeModel) {
                   TreeNodeModel nodeA = (TreeNodeModel)o1;
                   TreeNodeModel nodeB = (TreeNodeModel)o2;
                   String strA = (String)nodeA.getAttributes().get(RepcatTreeModel.ATTR_NAME);
                   String strB = (String)nodeB.getAttributes().get(RepcatTreeModel.ATTR_NAME);

                   if (strB.compareToIgnoreCase(strA) < 0)
                       result = 1;
                   else
                       if (strB.compareToIgnoreCase(strA) > 0)
                           result = -1;
               }
               else
                   if (o1 instanceof RowModel && o2 instanceof RowModel) {
                       RowModel nodeA = (RowModel)o1;
                       RowModel nodeB = (RowModel)o2;
                       String strTmp = (String)nodeA.getAttributes().get(RepcatTreeModel.ROW_ATTR_RDD_PATH);
                       String strA = strTmp.substring(strTmp.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                       strTmp = (String)nodeB.getAttributes().get(RepcatTreeModel.ROW_ATTR_RDD_PATH);
                       String strB = strTmp.substring(strTmp.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

                       if (strB.compareToIgnoreCase(strA) < 0)
                           result = 1;
                       else
                           if (strB.compareToIgnoreCase(strA) > 0)
                               result = -1;
                   }
               return result;
          }
       });
       items = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(_items));
       return items;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RepcatTree.getItems()` returns Strings instead of a object of your type. That is why you can't call `getType()` on item.

Comment: getItems returns expected type, but I don't understand why it's String. If I change <c:forEach items="#{repcatTree.items}" var="item"> to <c:forEach items="${repcatTree.items}" var="item"> I would be able to get my Object and work with it, but I can't work with it through HTML tags <h:commandLink rendered="#{item.type == 'report'}" styleClass="default_link" 
                    action="action_report_run" title="#{item.cells['report_name'].toolTip}"> because it's empty. I can get values only with jstl through ${} expression.

Comment: When I tried to display item it's output like a String "repcatTree.items"

Comment: can you post your `RecaptTree`class?

Comment: I add my class to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`#{repcatTree.items}` returns a List of String objects.

On the two `<h:commandLink>` components, change their `rendered` attributes from

```
rendered="#{item.type == 'category'}"
```

to

```
rendered="#{item eq 'category'}"
```

Comment: #{repcatTree.items} returns my type object, please see below comment.

Comment: Just for information that may help: We use JFS1.2 with  <class-loader delegate="false" />
 <property name="useMyFaces" value="true"/><!-- Glassfish V2 -->
 <property name="useBundledJsf" value="true"/><!-- Glassfish V3 -->

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am sure #{repcatTree.items} should return right my type object because in case of immediate expression${repcatTree.items} it returns correct values, but It's impossible to use jstl variables in jsf tags. I'll be really appreciated for any other suggestions that help to resolve my problem. Thanks a lot.